# Where can I find a presentation on SharePoint to encourage management buy-in?

Tags: recommendations

I need a presentation or similar material based on a project manager's perspective, in order to prepare my own presentation to convince my management to buy SharePoint 2010 Standard.

My presentation will be about what we can do using Standard Edition and its benefits.

Comment: Do you have any particular business need you are trying to fulfill? Content Management? Team Collaboration? SharePoint is huge if you could target specific use cases and show the expected return on investment your presentation would be much more compelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to slideshare.net and search for "SharePoint 2010 Business Features" and a few other search variations and you will find tons of presentations on the business benefits of SharePoint. It is your best resource to help prepare for a presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a management presentation, but take a look at http://iusesharepoint.com/ , a new portal with adoption kits for SharePoint